# enviar id de la vista al controlador con php

Tags: php, html5

Tengo una vista donde listo todas las actividades almacenadas en mi base de datos, en cada actividad tengo un ancla para editar cada registro, este es el codigo en la vista

```
<?php foreach ($a as $value): ?>
    <li class="liAdmin">
      <div class="divAcmin">
        <?php echo $value->video_url; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="divAcmin2">
        <h3><?php echo $value->nombre; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $value->contenido; ?></p>
        <h5 class="h5Acmin"><?php echo $value->clasificacion; ?></h5>
      </div>
      <a href="<?php echo SERVERURL;?>editarActividad/<?php echo $value->id ?>" action="editar"><h5>Editar Actividad</h5>  </a>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

aca cargo casa vista y en el ancla le coloco el id de cada actividad para que lo mande por url al controlador, este es el codigo en el controlador

```
if (isset($_GET['views']) && $_GET['views']== 'editarActividad') {
$editaractividad = new actividadControlador();
$instanciaactividad->mostrarActividad($id);
```

}

en la vista al colocar el cursor sobre el ancla de editar accion me muestra esta url
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi duda es, al momento de darle al ancla de editar como puedo enviar ese datos al controlador para de alli hacer una funcion yu consultar en la base de datos.

Comment: con javascript y ajax y un evento onclick.

Comment: Cuando des click en el ancla de editar, puedes crear una variable de sesión e igualarla al valor del id. Ejemplo:

session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;

Y usas esa variable de sesión para tus consultas.

Comment: claro, pero el detalle es que me lo solicitan sin esas tecnologias

Comment: @EdgarSaavedra podrias darme un ejemplo de como hacerlo

Comment: @AngelGutierrez ya edité mi comentario amigo